# Use gstreamer to remux a single title out of a DVD without re encoding

Tags: gstreamer, video-processing, video-encoding, gstreamer-1.0

I am trying to re-mux the video of a specific title out of a DVD into a video file, without decoding then re-encoding the video.

I have this pipeline that works exactly the way I want for audio, and theoretically would work the way I want for video, but drops most video buffers due to

```
matroskamux matroska-mux.c:4035:gst_matroska_mux_write_data:<mux:video_0>
    Invalid buffer timestamp; dropping buffer
```

The resulting video file plays, but is a slideshow, as one would expect given all the dropped video buffers.

Here's the pipeline in question

```
#!/bin/bash
TITLE=2
DVD=~/BATTSTAR_GALAC_S1_D2.iso
GST_DEBUG=2                                         \
gst-launch-1.0 -v -e                                \
    dvdreadsrc title=${TITLE} device=${DVD}         \
        ! mpegpsdemux name=demux                    \
                                                    \
    multiqueue name=queue                           \
        demux. ! 'video/mpeg'           ! queue.    \
        demux. ! 'audio/x-private1-ac3' ! queue.    \
                                                    \
    matroskamux name=mux                            \
        queue. ! mpegvideoparse ! mux.              \
        queue. ! ac3parse       ! mux.              \
                                                    \
    mux. ! filesink location=~/test.mkv
```

Here's another version of the same pipeline where I tried to inject timestamping, which also does not work.

```
#!/bin/bash
TITLE=2
DVD=~/BATTSTAR_GALAC_S1_D2.iso
GST_DEBUG=2                                         \
gst-launch-1.0 -v -e                                \
    dvdreadsrc do-timestamp=true ! title=${TITLE} device=${DVD} \
        ! mpegpsdemux name=demux ignore-scr=true    \
                                                    \
    multiqueue name=queue                           \
        demux. ! 'video/mpeg'           ! queue.    \
        demux. ! 'audio/x-private1-ac3' ! queue.    \
                                                    \
    matroskamux name=mux                            \
        queue. ! mpegvideoparse disable-passthrough=true ! mux. \
        queue. ! ac3parse       disable-passthrough=true ! mux. \
                                                    \
    mux. ! filesink location=~/test.mkv
```

Thinking that perhaps something is wrong with the multiqueue, or with syncronizing the video and the audio, I can still reproduce the choppy video (dropped buffers) by removing the audio component of the pipeline and switching from multiqueue to queue (not queue2, that ends the pipeline before it gets to the end, I don't know why other than speculating a bug).

```
#!/bin/bash
TITLE=2
DVD=~/BATTSTAR_GALAC_S1_D2.iso
GST_DEBUG=1                                 \
gst-launch-1.0 -v -e                        \
    dvdreadsrc title=${TITLE} device=${DVD} \
        ! mpegpsdemux name=demux            \
                                            \
    queue name=videoqueue                   \
        demux. ! 'video/mpeg' ! videoqueue. \
                                            \
    matroskamux name=mux                    \
        videoqueue. ! mpegvideoparse ! mux. \
                                            \
    mux. ! filesink location=~/test.mkv
```

Since I speculate a bug in queue2, what if I remove the queue entirely? Still has the problem.

```
#!/bin/bash
TITLE=2
DVD=~/BATTSTAR_GALAC_S1_D2.iso
GST_DEBUG=1                                 \
gst-launch-1.0 -v -e                        \
    dvdreadsrc title=${TITLE} device=${DVD} \
        ! mpegpsdemux                       \
        ! mpegvideoparse                    \
        ! matroskamux                       \
        ! filesink location=~/test.mkv
```

An important note is that I can *play* the video *JUST FINE* with gstreamer, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
TITLE=2
DVD=~/BATTSTAR_GALAC_S1_D2.iso
GST_DEBUG=2                                 \
gst-launch-1.0 -v -e                        \
    dvdreadsrc title=${TITLE} device=${DVD} \
        ! mpegpsdemux                       \
        ! mpegvideoparse                    \
        ! mpeg2dec                          \
        ! autovideosink
```

and the same with working audio and video

```
#!/bin/bash
TITLE=2
DVD=~/BATTSTAR_GALAC_S1_D2.iso
GST_DEBUG=2                                         \
gst-launch-1.0 -v -e                                \
    dvdreadsrc title=${TITLE} device=${DVD}         \
        ! mpegpsdemux name=demux                    \
                                                    \
    multiqueue name=queue                           \
        demux. ! 'video/mpeg'           ! queue.    \
        demux. ! 'audio/x-private1-ac3' ! queue.    \
                                                    \
        queue. ! mpegvideoparse ! mpeg2dec ! autovideosink  \
        queue. ! ac3parse       ! a52dec   ! autoaudiosink
```

So this is *not* a problem of the source video being bad, it's entirely something that's missing from the pipeline.

I can even play the video while re-muxing it, and the on-screen video is smooth, but the file saved to disk is choppy

```
#!/bin/bash
TITLE=2
DVD=~/BATTSTAR_GALAC_S1_D2.iso
GST_DEBUG=2                                     \
gst-launch-1.0 -v -e                            \
    dvdreadsrc title=${TITLE} device=${DVD}     \
        ! mpegpsdemux name=demux                \
                                                \
    tee name=vtee                               \
    tee name=atee                               \
        demux. ! mpegvideoparse ! vtee.         \
        demux. ! ac3parse       ! atee.         \
                                                \
    multiqueue name=playqueue                   \
    multiqueue name=convqueue                   \
        vtee. ! playqueue.                      \
        vtee. ! convqueue.                      \
        atee. ! playqueue.                      \
        atee. ! convqueue.                      \
                                                \
        playqueue. ! decodebin ! autovideosink  \
        playqueue. ! decodebin ! autoaudiosink  \
                                                \
    matroskamux name=mux                        \
        convqueue. ! mux.                       \
        convqueue. ! mux.                       \
                                                \
    mux. ! filesink location=~/test.mkv
```

And here's a version of the pipeline that decodes the mpeg video and then re-encodes mpeg video. This version produces a video file that is not a slideshow, but has the problem of needing to re-encode the video. I don't want to re-encode the video, I want to take it "as is".

```
#!/bin/bash
TITLE=2
DVD=~/BATTSTAR_GALAC_S1_D2.iso
GST_DEBUG=2                                         \
gst-launch-1.0 -v -e                                \
    dvdreadsrc title=${TITLE} device=${DVD}         \
        ! mpegpsdemux name=demux                    \
                                                    \
    multiqueue name=queue                           \
        demux. ! 'video/mpeg'           ! queue.    \
        demux. ! 'audio/x-private1-ac3' ! queue.    \
                                                    \
    matroskamux name=mux                            \
        queue. ! mpegvideoparse ! mpeg2dec ! mpeg2enc ! mux. \
        queue. ! ac3parse       ! mux.              \
                                                    \
    mux. ! filesink location=~/test.mkv
```

Note that I'm using gstreamer version 1.20.4, compiled and installed on Gentoo Linux. It is possible that the 1.22 release series may have a fix for my problem, but I don't see anything on the release notes that make me think this was addressed: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/releases/1.22/

---

So what am I missing from my pipeline that prevents the buffers read from the DVD from having a valid timestamp when they get to the matroskamux ?

Comment: **(1)** Relax with the edits. Doing 5 edits in less than 1 hour can begin to trigger the system to consider blocking your account from further editing this post (until some cooldown period). **(2)** Does muxing into a MOV container work better than MKV for smooth playback? **(3)** Why is your DVD file a compressed ISO instead of a media VOB? Maybe extract a test VOB first from the ISO, then remux that VOB (or better, extract it's actual a/v content) into a MOV or a MKV... PS: I don't use GStreamer so I cannot tell you about its settings.

Comment: @VC.One (1) Noted. (2) Both qtmux and mp4mux result in files that have working audio but no video displayed by vlc. (3)The ISO file is not compressed, it's just ripped from disk. The same problems manifest if i substitute /dev/sr0 in the pipeline, it's just slower.

Comment: Okay. About VLC: does it report any video codec under media properties? Just wondering what it says... About ISO: Yes it's all the individual media files (and subtitles, etc) compressed into one ISO. You need an ISO viewer to see the [contained VOB files](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/wp-content/uploads/2004/03/mounted-iso-image-in-ubuntu-linux-file-manager.jpg) (a **V**ideo **OB**ject itself will contain further files embedded inside it, the MPEG-2 video stream and AC3 audio stream). Don't worry that GStreamer can play input media from the ISO itself, try muxing the actual raw media files.

Comment: Try **Furius ISO Mount** to view extract the ISO content. Get a VOB extracted, test playing it with VLC (confirm picture & sound is ok)... Then try that same VOB with GStreamer. PS: Are you open to trying alternative muxers like FFmpeg?

Comment: Mounting with `losetup -f -P -r ~/BATTSTAR_GALAC_S1_D2.iso && mount /dev/loop0 /tmp/mnt` , verifying that the VOBs work in VLC, and finally changing the pipeline to read a VOB file directly, has no effect, the video is still a slide-show, and the debugging output indicates thousands of dropped buffers. I am not open to trying ffmpeg, as gstreamer is being used as part of a larger solution, I need the problem with the gstreamer pipeline addressed specifically.

Comment: You're going to have to provide a testable file. Ideally for your question you want to upload the smallest media VOB that you've got. If possible, please first mux the VOB into MP4 then slice that to upload the first 30 to 50 mb for testing. MP4 structure makes it easier to debug frame contents and timestamps. To me, the slideshow effect is either because your output is made of only keyframes (if picture is changing every few seconds), or it's showing a still from each chapter's start point (if picture is changing after some minutes)

Comment: I'm not sure that uploading a sample VOB is going to do any good, the problem has reproduced on some dozen different files for me. I'm entirely certain that I'm using the gstreamer pipeline incorrectly. The issue is most likely between the mpegvideoparse and the matroskamux. Most likely some missing element that re-stamps the timestamp of the video. E.g similar to the `ffmpeg -fflags +genpts` option

Comment: Seems to be a bug in the `matroskamux` element. It works fine when using `mpegtsmux` (for me..). Even remuxing from that .ts file to a final .mkv seems to work just fine.

Comment: @Florian, thanks for the feedback. I'm going to try using a mpegtsmux as an intermediary and see what i get!

Comment: @FlorianZwoch you're right, converting to mpegtsmux produces smooth playback. Round-tripping through mpegtsmux to get to matroska gives me jittery playback but not "slideshow" playback. There's obviously some defect in the matroskamux.